# Stop Rounding with NSExpression in Calculator

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, nsexpression

I have built a simple text-based calculator with swift. It takes in an expression like `88+9*3` and spits out `115`. I am running in to a problem, however. When I do division (like `12/5`), the answer comes out rounded (with no decimals). I understand why (when this rounding happens, all of the numbers are integers, so it doesn't convert anything to floats), but **how do I stop the rounding when dividing integers?**

I can't just add .0 to the end of every number, because then things like 7.6.0 could happen (if the user types in something divided by `7.6`), resulting in a crash/no answer.

Here's my code:

```
func calculateString(calculatorinsert: String) throws -> String {
                var mathExpression = try NSExpression(format: nsexpress)
                var result:Float = try Float((mathExpression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber)!)
                if let calculated: Optional<Float> = result {
                    return String(result)
                } else {
                    return "Error"
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's the value of `nsexpress`?

Comment: NSExpression is a bit limited in its possibilities, and yes, integer division truncates the result. Appending ".0" – where necessary – is the only solution that I know of. Note that there are other math parsers, e.g. https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki (written in Objective-C, but usable from Swift).

Comment: @CodeDifferent It's just the same thing as calculatorinsert, sorry.